# How to debug my Fibonacci generator in MIPS assembly language?

Tags: mips

My code should accept a value n from the user to output the Fibonacci series. The code does not work from 4 and above. Also, how do I fix the code so that the fib series start from 0, not 1. The output of the code should be as follows if the user inputs 4

0 1 1 2

Here is the code

```
.data
string:.asciiz "Enter N: " # space to insert between numbers
space:.asciiz " " # space to insert between numbers
.text

la $a0, string
li $v0, 4   
syscall # print the string

li $v0,5 #read inetger in $t0
syscall
move $t0,$zero
addi $t0,$v0,-1
move $t1,$zero
addi $t1,$t1,1

move $s0,$zero
addi $s0,$s0,1


move $a0,$s0
li $v0, 1 # $integer to print

syscall


la $a0, space
li $v0, 4   
syscall # print the string


loop:

move $a0,$s0
li $v0, 1 # $integer to print
syscall


la $a0, space
li $v0, 4   
syscall # print the string

addi $t0,$t0,-1
beq $t0,$zero,stop

add $s0,$s0,$t1

sub $t1,$a0,$t1

j loop

stop:
li $v0, 10 # system call for exit
syscall # Exit!
```

Answer (score 0):

You've implemented the algorithm incorrectly. What you've written translates into something like this:

```
int prev1 = 1, fn = 1;
for (int n = 0; n < input; ++n) {
    printf("%d ", fn);
    fn += prev1;
    prev1 = &space - prev1;
}
```

But what you should have done is more like:

```
int prev2 = 0, prev1 = 1;
for (int n = 0; n < input; ++n) {
    int fn = prev1 + prev2;
    printf("%d ", prev2);
    prev2 = prev1;
    prev1 = fn;
}
```

---

Regarding the question from your title ("How to debug?"): SPIM (and its variants) and MARS both give you a lot of debugging features.
There's the code, data, and register viewers.
 You can single-step through your code (typically using the F10, but it may differ between different simulators), and also set breakpoints at code locations of particular interest.